# How to get all Active Directory user details using Search Filter Syntax

Tags: active-directory

How can I get all users properties like (email, address, phone and etc..)
using search filter syntax?

Can't find anything in the docs.

I tried this

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn=Erika Wynn))
```

but all I get is the dn details :

```
CN=Erika Wynn,CN=Users,DC=****,DC=local
```

I wish to get all user fields General (telephone, email..), Address (Street, City), Organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should of just provide a user name similar to AD login, as a filter and any attribute I needed to get.

I used this great article, to get all the different attributes that you can fetch from Active Directory. 
https://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/help/csv-import-management/active-directory-ldap-attributes.html

this is the query:

```
filter=(sAMAccountName=username) attributes=cn,department,company,streetAddress,L,st,co,mail
```

Answer (score 1):

LDAP allows you to specify which attributes you want to receive. If you do not specify anything, Active Directory will return every attribute that has a value. So if it is not doing that in your case, then there must be some part of the code that has set the list of attributes to only the `distinguishedName`.

You will have to show your code for us to help you more. You can update your question to include your code.